# Proof about Convolution integral, I'm wondering what the claim says.

Tags: calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ Lebesgue intgrable on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $g$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R^n}$ s.t. supp$(g)=\{ x\in \mathbb{R^n} \mid g(x)\neq 0 \}$ is compact.

And set $h(x)=\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R^n}} f(y)g(x-y) dy.$

Then, prove that $h(x)$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R^n}.$

The claim says that prove that $h(x)$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R^n}$.

But I'm wondering what this says.

If this means $\displaystyle\int_{R^n} |f(y)g(x-y)| dy <\infty,$ I could prove since
\begin{align}
\displaystyle\int_{R^n} |f(y)g(x-y)| dy \leqq M \int_{\mathbb{R^n}} |f(y)| dy < \infty
\end{align}holds since supp$(g)$ is compact and there exists $M>0$ s.t. $|f(y)g(x-y)|\leqq M|f(y)|$ and $f$ is integrable.

But the claim says ''$h$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^n$'' so should  I have to prove $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|h(x) |dx <\infty$ ?

If so, I don't know how I can prove.

I'd like you to give me any help.

Comment: Yes, you have to prove your second statement, since the first one only shows that $h$ exists (and your proof for the existance of $h$ is correct).

Comment: If $g$ is continuous and not identically zero then $\{x:g(x)\ne0\}$ is **not** compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int |h(x)|dx \leq \int \int |f(y)g(x-y)|dy dx=\int \int |f(y)g(x-y)|dx dy$$ by Fubini/Tonelli Theorem. So $$\int |h(x)|dx \leq \int \int g(x-y)|dx |f(y)|dy$$ $$=\int \int g(u)|du |f(y)|dy$$ by the change of variable $u=x-y$. So we get $\int |h(x)|dx \leq \int |f(x)|dx \int |g(x)|dx<\infty$. [Note that $g$ continuous with compact support implies that $\int |g(x)|dx<\infty$].

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $$\text{Supp}(g)=\overline{\{x\in \mathbb R^n\mid g(x)\neq 0\}},$$
and not what you wrote. Then, you indeed need to prove that $$\int_{\mathbb R^n}|h(x)|\,\mathrm d x<\infty .$$

To do it :

$$\int_{\mathbb R^n}|h(x)|\,\mathrm d x\underset{Tonelli}{=}\int_{\mathbb R^n}|f(y)|\int_{\mathbb R^n}|g(x-y)|\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\underset{s=x-y}{=}\int_{\mathbb R^n}|f(y)|\,\mathrm d y\int_{\mathbb R^n}|g(s)|\,\mathrm d s<\infty. $$